# selenium webdriver chrome page keeps loading

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have create a simple bot that at the entry of the betfair website will simply click the accept cookies button. Its been working for months but now all of a sudden once entered the page, it will just keep loading without performing the action. Any idea why?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time



url = r"C:\Users\salde\Desktop\chromedriver_win32 (1)\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=url)

##website to navigate to
driver.get('https://www.betfair.com/exchange/plus/')

##to accept cookies at the entry to the website

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]'))
)
element.click()

time.sleep(2)

btnCookies = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]')
btnCookies.click()
```

Comment: " now all of a sudden once entered the page, it will just keep loading without performing the action" by this you mean, the page reloads over and over again, and none of the code after the `driver.get()` is executed?

Answer (score 1):

As you've defined them, your variables `element` and `btnCookies` target the same element, and you shouldn't need to click it twice. (In fact the second time, the element is now longer displayed, which is why you get the `element not interactable` error.  At least try cleaning up your code to remove these last few lines and see what happens:

```
time.sleep(2)

btnCookies = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]')
btnCookies.click()
```

Comment: Thats not the issue, I have to click the accept cookies button twice because it appears twice.

Comment: Weird, it goes away after just the one click for me.

Comment: yeah might be some issue with my chrome. thanks anyway